# Subtitle not showing in cell till cell is selected

Tags: uitableview

I have a simple table view with a subtitle style cell.
The very first time a cell is created the subtitle of the cell is not displayed until I select the cell. All other cells are created correctly.
Any ideas why this should be, or what i could do about it?
thanks
karl

The code to create the cell is simple, and works for all but the first ever cell:

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Course

    cell.textLabel!.text = object.courseName
    cell.textLabel!.textColor = appConstants.colors.appCellTitleColor

    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = object.courseBanner
    cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = appConstants.colors.appCellDetailTextColor

    //cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "TBC Logo, Tableview, Course, Clear")
}
```

Thanks

Comment: how do you add the subtitle to the cell?  if it's in code, show it...

Comment: cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = appConstants.colors.appCellDetailTextColor

appConstants.colors.appCellDetailTextColor  may be same as officer's background color. Check by setting any other color